# 'Credo' with dative problem

Tags: verbs, grammar-identification, dative

Here is a small problem with *'credo'*, there is an example in my dictionary saying that *'crede mihi* (dat.)' means *'believe me'*.

Gildersleeve & Lodge gives *credere* under *Dative with Intransitive verbs - "The Indirect Object is put in the Dative vith many Intranitive verbs of Advantage or Disadvantage, Yielding and resisting, Pleasure and Displeasure, Bidding and Forbidding*."

When I look now this sentence in Spinoza,

> Nam quandoquidem ejus essentia omnem imperfectionem secludit absolutamque perfectionem involvit, eo ipso omnem causam dubitandi de ipsius existentia tollit summamque de eadem certitudinem dat, **quod mediocriter attendenti perspicuum fore credo.<**

..., quod (that) mediocriter (moderately) attendenti (Pr. part. dat.) perspicuum (acc. adj.) fore (Fut. inf.) credo (here as Verba Declarandi, takes inf. and acc.).

'Attendenti' looks to be dative, but could it be here in dative not because of the first, *"Dative with intransitive verbs"* but because of *Dative with Transitive verbs - "The Indirect Object is put in the Dative with Transitive verbs, which already have a Direct object in the Accusative. Translation to, for, from.* " (Gildersleeve & Lodge) ? Is it possible that one verb can be intransitive and transitive in the same time, depending of the exact meaning?

When translated "I believe that it would be clear **to** moderately attentive"  - which sounds reasonable in English, but when looking at that first example given, 'crede mihi' then I would think *'quod perspicuum*' should be in Dative instead of '*attendenti* ' ?

Thank you.

Comment: The structure is *credo {quod attendenti perspicuum fore}*: *credo* has only one complement, which is the entire accusativus cum infinitivo,  *quod attendenti perspicuum fore*. The dative is no immediate complement to *credo*. Inside the a.c.i., the verb *fore* has three complements: 1. the 'subject' accusative *quod*; 2. the 'subject complement' accusative *perspicuum*; and 3. the indirect object *mediocriter attendenti*. All three are complements to *fore*. Translation: "...which I believe to be clear to [anyone] paying [even] mediocre attention".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Gildersleeve and Lodge call this *Dativus Iudicantis*, Dative of the person judging. It's specifying from whose perspective the statement is *perspicuum*: 'clear *to* (from the perspective of) the person who pays even moderate attention'

So, in this example, the dative isn't the object of *credo* at all.

**Update:** As to the question of whether it's possible for a verb to be used transitively and intransitively at the same time, the answer is yes, and *credo* is a verb that can do this (though not in this Spinoza passage). For example, in colloquial English, *omnia tibi credo*, would mean something like 'I believe (or 'trust') you in all matters' or 'I believe (or 'trust') everything you tell me' or 'I take your word in all matters.' It's a conflation of two separate constructions: the intransitive *tibi credo* ('I trust you') and the transitive *omnia credo* ('I believe everything'). I just recently ran across an example in Seneca's tragedy *Thyestes* (line 295): *cui tanta credet?* The commentary that I'm using points to other instances in Plautus and Ovid.

Comment: I think your answer is good, but I have one small remark. "Transitive" merely means that a verb has or normally has a direct object. That doesn't mean it can't have additional complements at the same time, such as an indirect object or yet another kind of complement. A verb can therefore not be both transitive and intransitive at the same time. In your example *omnia tibi credo*, the verb is transitive because it has a direct object.

Comment: Oh, and subject, direct object, indirect object, and ablative phrase are examples of common complements (not "objects") that verbs may have. Without specification, the term "object" alone normally refers only to direct objects, but it is always wise to specify the term if possible (i.e. direct object or object of a preposition).

Comment: @Cerberus Of course, the verb is actually transitive in _omnia tibi credo_, because it does actually have a direct obj. But one doesn't typically also find an indir. obj. with _credo_ when it has a direct obj. – that's typically a separate, intrans. use of the verb, a separate idiom. That was my point: these two, usually-separate idioms are being activated at the same time. Readers need to be aware of, and juggle, both idioms to make good sense of the text. So I can qualify my answer, I suppose, by saying that, _in effect_, it's _as if_ the verb were both trans. and intrans. at the same time.

Comment: @cnread: OK I understand your point; it is probably unusual for the two praedicate frames to be mixed like this. The example from Seneca is nice, and I agree with everything after the first sentence of the update. But I still wouldn't call the praedicate frame of *credo* + dativus "intransitive" in instances where the verb is used with a direct object: it is only intransitive to the extent that it doesn't have an object, and that ends at the moment it gets an object. Of course I understand that you're trying to humour the asker, and you wanted a name for that praedicate frame.

Comment: @Cerberus Your point is well-taken. I guess I approach this with an eye more on _effect_; so the fact that it's so unusual for the 2 frames to be mixed is exactly the point for me. It's as though Seneca in his phrase and I in mine want both frames to apply—and to be activated in the reader's mind—simultaneously. What we need is a sort of Heisenberg uncertainty principle: you can measure strict transitivity or the types of objects that _credo_ has, but not both. Okay, that's a bit sloppy, but space is limited. Still, I'll see if I can tighten up my response in light of your helpful comments.

Comment: I'll also add, as a general comment, that some speakers of languages other than English probably wouldn't find the double object with _credo_ difficult or surprising at all, but perfectly natural. Example: German _Das_ (accusative) _glaube ich dir_ (dative), 'I believe you (in) this' or 'I believe what you're saying.'

Comment: @Cerberus - there is really no need to humour me - "humour, verb - comply with the wishes of (someone) in order to keep them content, however unreasonable such wishes might be"

Comment: @AiliJ.: Oh, I did not mean it in such a negative way. I meant "follow someone's train of thought as a nice gesture".